# Stack around the variable was corrupted when using sscanf_s

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, scanf, unsigned-integer

I quiet do not understand why I get error "Stack around the variable "tmp" was corrupted".

I use same code in different functions and it works well but now when function is "returning" it throws error mentioned above.

```
struct frame {
   uint8_t dst[6]; 
   uint8_t src[6];    
};

//fill frame.dst || src exactly same way as code below without any errors or warnings

bool fcn() {

    uint8_t tmp[6];

    sscanf_s("00-00-00-00-00-00", "%x-%x-%x-%x-%x-%x", &tmp[0], &tmp[1], &tmp[2], &tmp[3], &tmp[4], &tmp[5]);
    //here I compare tmp[0] == frame.mac[0]...
    return true; 
} //here pops the error while debugging
```

I use exactly same code in different part of the program but no error what so ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring **C-Standard confirming** systems:

To scan in an 8bit value on a 32bit machine, one needs to use the `"hh"` length modifier. The half of the half of `32` is `8`.

---

For VC one needs to use a workaround scanning into `unsigned int`s.

Comment: So this is on Visual C, isn't it?

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Thanks, can you do a brief example I somehow can not make it "run".

Comment: When scanning into `u_int` do I have to use `"hh"`, `"hx"` or `"x"`

Comment: To scan in hex from a "string" into `unsigned int` use `"x"`. `u_int` isn't a standard type, so I cannot say which conversion specifier to use. @Kyslik

Comment: It should be just `typdef` of `unsigned int`, I got it working I hope there is no undetected "leak".

Answer (score 2):

The `%x` specifier writes to an `int` parameter, but you are passing pointers to `uint8_t` instead. Since `int` is a larger type on your platform, you are overwriting memory when those fields are written out. Pass in pointers to `int` instead and convert them to your required type as appropriate.

You will want to do this everywhere else you use this code too!

Comment: Can you explain why in one function it works but in second one it does not? Why system does not detect "error" in a first place?

Comment: In this case you are overwriting a part of the stack used to properly return from the function. In other cases you are overwriting memory too, but you happen to not overwrite anything that makes a noticeable difference in your code, e.g. you might be overwriting some padding for alignment or a local variable on the stack that's no longer used. You'll want to fix this everywhere since changing, say, compiler versions, or modifying the surrounding code, could easily result in a "noticeable" problem.

Comment: Thanks to above comment now I understand why.